Getting all my Facebook comments with permalinks
I'd like to download all my Facebook comments with permalinks. Normal data export just gives me a JSON with comments, but there is no permalink in it, so I don't know what I replied to.
I found there is a graph API, but I was not able to generate an access token for it. I got the error message that the feature is not available. Do you know any way to get the permalinks somehow?
We are talking about a few thousand comments I think, but even manual ways would be a help.
On the Facebook user interface I cannot go back enough years to do it there. Sadly it has its own limits.
